# Get relative coordinates of dragged element in snap.svg

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I'm trying to write my own `onmove` event handler for the snap.svg [`Element.drag` function](http://snapsvg.io/docs/#Element.drag). I want to allow the element to be dragged but constrain it to a certain area. To do that, I need the coordinates of the mouse relative to the svg's top left corner (0,0) but the handler is provided with x and y arguments that are absolute positions in the document. This seems rather useless given that positioning in the svg is all relative to its top left corner, and not the document. Is there a way of getting the relative coordinates without using something like jQuery `.offset` to get the absolute position of the svg?

Comment: Here's an example I've done before which may help get you going. It could probably be written a bit more efficient/concise though http://svg.dabbles.info/snaptut-drag-limit

Comment: Thanks, @Ian. I saw that but had some reservations about it. First I don't understand how LimitDrag actually works. Second, it looks like it's moving the element using a transform, but I want to actually change my element's X & Y...at least I think I do. Mostly just for simplicitiy's sake. Third I noticed the comment "this code is old and clunky now, and transform possibly in wrong order..." which dissuaded me from looking into it further. I think the second one is where I run into a problem that your code avoids. Since I actually move the element, I have dx/dy but I lose the origin.

Comment: However, perhaps I could solve that by storing an `ox` and `oy` as data at the start of a drag like it appears you do. Then I think `dx + ox` and `dy + oy` would be the relative offset from 0,0.